Is there a term for being able to start a simulation at any valid state of the system
For many applications of simulations (e.g. discrete event simulation) it is valuable to set the initial conditions of the simulation. For planning purposes this is often the current state of the system of interest, but it could be other possible starting points.
In some cases we're interested in some form of long-term stationary distribution, in which case a sufficiently-long warmup phase may be sufficient. But sometimes the initial conditions, especially for non-stationary systems, can be very important to the evolution of the system.
Is there a term describing a simulation system/tool in which it can be initialized to be in any state? The term bouncing around my head is "initialization completeness", but I'm quite sure I made that one up.
